# Huge asynchronous compute work stalls rendering in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, gpu, shader, vulkan

I have a usual rendering loop and some big compute dispatches running on a dedicated queue from a compute-only family. They are running on a single VkDevice, but otherwise are completely independent. Compute work basically consists of a single dispatch, which can take up to a few seconds to complete. And I see freezes up to 200ms in rendering with that compute work running in background, though if I reduce a compute workload so that it takes around 0.5sec, there're no lags at all. I use Nvidia Quadro T2000 on Windows, priorities for rendering and compute queues are 1.0 and 0.0 respectively.

I guess splitting compute work into separate smaller submits would help, but I am wondering what can cause such behavior? Or maybe which profiling tools can help me diagnosing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teh Vulkan specc:

> There are no implicit ordering constraints between queue operations on different queues, or between queues and the host, so these **may** operate in any order with respect to each other. Explicit ordering constraints between different queues or with the host **can** be expressed with *semaphores* and *fences*.

---

> priorities for rendering and compute queues are 1.0 and 0.0 respectively.

→

> No specific guarantees are made about higher priority queues receiving more processing time or better quality of service than lower priority queues.

---

Additionally, if you let something run for couple of seconds, it has a tendency to trigger a watchdog on modern operating systems. You could check whether the hitch is caused by driver restart.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the spec, just hoped for some low-level details. But anyway, main conclusion is not to run any dispatches for seconds, because it can cause instabilities.